# Kendo UI TreeView not displaying remote data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

Hi I am trying to bind a Kendo UI Treeview to a ASP.NET MVC 4 controller. I have tried to follow the information in the Kendo UI demo on [TreeViews](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/remote-data.html) with remote data. As Far as I can tell the JSON being returned seems correct, could there be an issue with the encapsulating object around the data array?

**View Code**

```
<div class="treeview-back" style="padding: 10px">
<h3>Groups</h3>
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeviewGroup")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("GroupsRead", "Group")
        )
    )
)
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public class GroupController : Controller
{
    private IUserService _userService;

    public GroupController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
    //
    // GET: /GroupManage/

    public ActionResult ManageGroup()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GroupsRead([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var groups = _userService.GetAllGroups();

        List<GroupTreeViewModel> treeViewGroups = new List<GroupTreeViewModel>();
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            treeViewGroups.Add(new GroupTreeViewModel()
                {
                    id = group.Id,
                    Description = group.Description,
                    Name = "Test Node",
                    text = "Body of test node",
                    hasChildren = false,
                    ParentId = null 

                }
            );
        }
        return Json(treeViewGroups.ToDataSourceResult(request),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**Returned Json

```
{"Data":[{"Name":"Test Node","Description":"Full","text":"Body of test node","id":1,"hasChildren":false,"ParentId":null},{"Name":"Test Node","Description":"Platform 1","text":"Body of test node","id":2,"hasChildren":false,"ParentId":null}],"Total":2,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}
```

## Update

I solved the problem. The returned json data was layed out differently that the treeview was expecting. The treeview expected an array of nodes,instead I was sending that array wrapped in another object.

I fixed this by removing the call to .ToDataSourceRequest()

```
return Json(treeViewGroups,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: need more info - specifically, what are you seeing vs what are you expecting? are you getting an error in the web page? is it showing anything at all, or nothing at all? or ???

Comment: I am expecting a treeview with two items at the root level, at this point I am not seeing anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend checking the remote binding demo: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/remote-data.html. Check the ASP.NET MVC tab - the controller and the cshtml.

One problem that I see is using DataSourceRequest - the treeview doesn't use it.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the treeview isnt using the DataSourceRequest? I have already been using the kendoui demo, I linked to that page in my original question. In terms of the controller and the view I can't really see where I differ from the demo.

Comment: The controller from the linked demo doesn't use the DataSourceRequest class. Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

You had created the view from JSON method (GroupsRead()). Instead you must create a view form other than JSON method.
Eg:

```
    **//Create a view from ManageGroup() and call the Json** 
// Below Razor code created in ManaeGroup()
<div class="treeview-back" style="padding: 10px">
<h3>Groups</h3>
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeviewGroup")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("GroupsRead", "Group")
        )
    )
)
</div>
```